# Hierachical time-series clustering by labels in 'base' and 'dplyr'

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, hierarchical-clustering, timeserieschart

I want to do a hierarchical time series clustering of financial data from eurostat for EU-27 countries. I want to group values by time-series at first, and then add country name as labels in dendrogram.

Here is the head of my data:

```
> head(data)
  geo  unit coicop       time values    name   label
1  AT RCH_A   CP00 2001-04-01    2.6 Austria Austria
2  AT RCH_A   CP00 2007-03-01    1.9 Austria Austria
3  AT RCH_A   CP00 2011-09-01    3.9 Austria Austria
4  AT RCH_A   CP00 2018-10-01    2.4 Austria Austria
5  AT RCH_A   CP00 2017-03-01    2.1 Austria Austria
```

So many dates for one country.

I tried at first to group values by time_series, make distance matrix and hierarchical clusting and then add country name labels while presenting a plot:

```
df_long <- aggregate(values~time, data=data, FUN=mean)

hc <- hclust(dist(df_long[,"values"], method="minkowski", p=1.5), method="average")

plot(hc, labels=data$name, hang=-1)
```

But as you can expect I get an error:

```
> plot(hc, labels=data$name, hang=-1)
Error in graphics:::plotHclust(n1, merge, height, order(x$order), hang,  : 
  invalid dendrogram input
```

Way that has been choosed by me is fine or should I go another way to cluster time-series?

I already got mean values clutering only by countries, but I want to compare values from every date between countries.

Full code:

```
data <- get_eurostat("prc_hicp_manr")

data <- filter(data, time >= "2000-03-01" & time <= "2022-09-30" & coicop == "CP00")


country_name <- eurostat::eu_countries


data <- merge(data, country_name, by.x = "geo", by.y = "code")

unique(data$name)

data <- filter(data, name != "" & name != "United Kingdom")

unique(data$name)

sum(is.na(data$name))


ggplot(data) +
  aes(x = time, y = values, colour = name) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_hue(direction = 1) +
  labs(title = "Przebiegi HICP dla krajow UE") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20L, hjust = 0.5))

head(data)

data_by_country <- data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(values)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.matrix()


data_by_country <- as.data.frame(data_by_country)

rownames(data_by_country) <- data_by_country$name

plot(hclust(dist(data_by_country[, "value", drop=F], method = "minkowski", p = 1,5), method = "complete"), main = "Clustering countries based on HICP", xlab = NA, sub = NA)

hc <- hclust(dist(data_by_country[, "value", drop=F], method = "minkowski", p = 1,5), method = "complete")

clusters <- cutree(hc, 4)

rect.hclust(hc, k = 4, border = "red")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, however I see a mistake in your code. Namely, you are applying `dist` to a data.frame containing two columns: `values` and `time`, whereas you probably just want to measure the distance between `values`. correct?

Comment: Additionally, the number of items in the `hc` object (rows of `df_long`) may be less than the rows of `data`, due to the `aggregate` operation. Therefore, the `labels = data$name` may be causing the error because it contains more elements than the items in the dendrogram.

Comment: Please provide a more representative example

Comment: 1. Yes, my mistake in the original code. It should be df_long[, "values]. I will edit it.

Comment: My original data is is "prc_hicp_manr" dataset from Eurostat. There are time-series for countries in Europe and I want to make a hierarchical time-series clustering and show country name as labels. I already got a dendrogram clustered when mean values are clustered only by country names, but I want to compare values from every date between countries.

Comment: Uploaded full code in original post. It will be easier that way

Comment: hclust is meant for one row per observation.  In other words, your input data should have one row per time series with numerical columns.  You may need to engineer features for the time series that capture its seasonality, trend, etc. and cluster based on these rather than the time series value.  Or, standardize the time series values and pivot wider so the values are in columns rather than rows.